# Checkered material ends up stretching despite seemingly proper UV unwrapping

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

My simple cylinder gets stretched tilted checkers on the sides when I unwrap -
[image]

This is how my unwrap looks like -
[image]

I have applied all transformations as well.

Attaching the .blend as well.
Many thanks!

Comment: In Object mode with object selected open the Apply menu with Ctrl + A and choose the rotation option. If needed Unwrap a second time .

Comment: Add a texture coordinates node and plug its 'UV' output to the 'Vector' input of the checker texture node. You may have to rotate the UV map after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Checker texture is actually 3D - it divides the texture space into cubes.

There are actually 2 things going on here:

Your tree is missing the nodes illustrated below:

[image]

First thing:

In Blender, a procedural texture-space will default to 'Generated' if texture coordinates are not explicitly provided. Generated space is measured (0-1, min->max) along the sides of an object's bounding box.

As  @3fingeredfrog has commented, the rotation of your mesh is not aligned with its object's axes, as you can see from the bounding box. So the mesh is at an angle to the Generated texture space. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>  > applying rotation with the mesh aligned to the world would fix that.

Second thing:

(As @lemon has commented) Without the mapping nodes, the texture is not using your UV map; it's having no influence. If you *do* use the UV map, then a 2D slice at Z=0 (W=0)is taken out of the Checker texture,  mapped  0-1 in U and V. The shading points in your object look up the texture from that space, using the UV map you've provided, with the result shown in the picture.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I had no idea there was a pipeline behind this. Your answer perfectly explained what I need, but could you please direct me to what I should learn to understand the 'why' behind it? The very basics of what this tree is about.

Comment: If you have time to get into the weeds,I think  [Bartek Skorupa's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0)  is really nice.

Comment: @Krishnabm .. I've just had a look back at it .. it's still very good on the principles, but Blender's shader nodes have improved a lot since then. There are inputs on the mapping nodes, and you don't have to use RGB to simulate XYZ any more.. I'll try to find other things..